# Unable to call getFile() from ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Hi i created file upload kind of thing, in which i would like to provide the upload file 
  size validation i wrote the following code worked fine in chrome and firefox.

```
$('#file').change(function() {  
 fileSizeError = (this.files[0].size/(1024*1024) > 1) ? true:false;     
});
```

But this code is not working in IE, i would like to implement the same in the following 
  fashion

```
        var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var filePath = $('#file')[0].value;
            var theFile = myFSO.getFile(filePath);
            alert('Rajaram');
            var size = theFile.size;
            alert(size + " bytes");
```

Here myproblem is myFSO.getFile() is notworking .the alert is not prompted

Comment: Any errors in the console? Other than `newActiveXObject(..)`, which should be `new ActiveXObject(..)`?

Comment: SCRIPT53: File not found

Comment: the file original path :C:\Users\durga_sambhani\Desktop\Test Data_1mb.docx but the filePath variable shows like this C:\fakePath\Test Data_1mb.docx

Comment: @user2590163: Yes. The path given to you by the `input` element is always fake, to prevent your knowing things about the user's file system.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution for calculating the uploaded file size in IE

Answer (score 2):

> Here my problem is myFSO.getFile() is not working

Thank Heaven for that! Otherwise, anyone browsing websites with IE would be in a *lot* of trouble very quickly, as malicious sites would access their files.

Access to the local file system through a wide-open API like `FileSystemObject` is simply not allowed for Internet Zone content. (The only way to use an *Unsafe for Scripting* ActiveX control in IE is to put the page in the TRUSTED security zone and lower that Zone's security slider to *Low*.)

The HTML5 File API is *dramatically* more locked-down, giving JavaScript restricted access only to the limited set of files the user has selected.

Comment: Thank u , but how can i find the file size

Comment: @user2590163: You can't, not in IE < 10.

Comment: @EricLaw: Great edit, thank you, I think I was really rushed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var FSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
FSO.GetFile("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe")
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem if the getFile() produce fakePath, try to get the fileName from the path and give that to getFile() and rest of them is working fine

```
var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fileName = ($('#file')[0].value).split('\\');
var fileDtls = myFSO.getFile(fileName[fileName.length-1]);
alert(fileDtls.size);
```

Alert Displays uploaded file size